# Replace empty string ''" from req.body with value null/undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to change empty strings to undefined or null, when req.body contains a key with value "".

I have googled around for a long time and I might be looking into it from the wrong way, as I am a total amateur, but I could only find how to validate whether the input is empty string. The thing is I don't want empty strings saved in my database, but those fields aren't required, so validation is not helping here.

I know that one way to address this would be going through the the req.body JSON and change the values before saving, but it doesn't sound like the best way to do it.

Is it possible to do it using mongoose?

```
const car = new CarSchema()
Object.assign(car, req.body) //same time replace '' -> undefined
car.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove or convert those properties from your existing doc, set them to undefined for remove this key in your docs, or set null if the the value is `""` before saving the doc:

```
user.first_name = user.first_name ? user.first_name : undefined;
user.signup_date = user.signup_date ? user.signup_date : undefined;
user.save();
```

OR:

```
user.first_name = user.first_name ? user.first_name : null;
user.signup_date = user.signup_date ? user.signup_date : null;
user.save();
```

By the way you are referring to [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) (Schema Types), you can go to the Arrays explanation. There, it says this:

> To overwrite this default, you need to set the `default` value to
>   `undefined` or `null`. Of course, when we create and quantify our own schema

```
var car = new Schema({
     toys: {
          type: [{
              name: String,
              features: [String]
          }],
          default: undefined //or null
     }
})
```

After that it is not possible or you have to code Mongo inside. That doesn't matter, both are object processing, either in Mongo or within JavaScript. Mongo gives you what you have saved and needs to be processed in the same way as JavaScript.